# Why can I no longer use Paypal Adaptive Payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm a software developer, and my client wants to facilitate payments between buyers and sellers, while charging a handling fee.

The workflow would be:

1. Seller puts product for sale on site
2. Buyer puts product in cart
3. Buyer clicks checkout
4. Buyer is redirect to paypal hosted payment page
5. Buyer enters credit card info on paypal
6. Buyer is redirected to application
7. Application sends payment request, gets transaction id back
8. Main payment is sent to Seller account, handling fee is sent to my Client's account

I was looking at [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/) as a solution, and it seems like a good fit. However, the text shown at the top of the page say's that you now need PayPal's permission to start a new product with it.

PayPal's docs don't really explain if there is a new method for doing this... What's the proper way to achieve this workflow in Paypal?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Chained Payments for this. It's important that both primary receiver and secondary receiver are tracked in same transaction.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

To be able to request permissions to use this services in your business account you need to submit a new application request to PayPal where you describe which type of services will you use. They will accept or decline your application and if accepted they will deliver an APP-ID so you can execute API requests in LIVE mode. You will also need CLIENT_ID and SECRET_ID, you can find them in your REST API keys present in your account.

To submit an application there will be an option in your developer account that says NVP/SOAP API apps and you will click on manage NVP/SOAP API apps and fill one out if you have not already.

As a side note from personal experience: If you try using Express Checkout and then MassPay, PayPal will not approve your business application because, and I quote, "They don't have visibility of initial payments". The only option is to use Chained Payments or Parallel Payments.

I had Express Checkout and Implicit Adaptive Payments set and my business application was denied. So I suggest you stick to using chained payments.